# How to restore an old version in Google Apps Script's new editor?

Tags: google-apps-script, version-control

Google Apps Script's old editor can have old versions of its scripts restored by using Google's standard `File=>See version history` (standard as in Google Drive).

However, the new editor doesn't seem to have the top toolbar at all (File, etc.).

Does it mean Google dropped the ability to restore/roll back old versions (unless you can - for the time being at least - restore the old editor itself)? Or is there another way?

[image: See version history]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new editor doesn't include a built-in feature to restore a version.

The old workaround of using the legacy editor is no longer possible as Google retired it in September 2022.

To restore a project old version, you have to someway get the old version and overwrite the head deployment. This could be done with the help of the Google Apps Script API.

There are several tools that can help with this like CLASP and web browser extensions. I have used [Google Apps Script GitHub Assistant](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-apps-script-github/lfjcgcmkmjjlieihflfhjopckgpelofo?hl=en), it works very well but it requires a third-party Git service like GitHub, BitBucked, etc. For small projects this might be overkilling. Lately for most of my solo projects I use CLASP which is a command line tool.

NOTES:

Nowadays is possible to create a new version from the DEPLOY button. It's possible to use it to set the version to be used by a deployment, but not to restore a version as the HEAD version (the current content).

## Resources

### Google Apps Scripts

#### Guides

- [Command Line Interface using clasp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp)
- [Explore the developement environment > Versions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/versions)
- [How to... > Manage versions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/manage-versions)

#### API reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/getContent
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/updateContent

#### Release notes

In September 2022 Google retired the legacy editor.

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases#september_2022

Comment: What's the benefit of point 1. if you can't use it to restore?

Comment: If you are planning to restore a version later, you don't have to go to the old editor to save a version.

Comment: I understand that, but I don't think it's related to the DEPLOY button. All you need to do is save like you always do. Then if you switch to the old version again, you'll be able to restore all these saves.

Comment: How to open the legacy editor today?

Comment: @vstepaniuk It's not possible as it was retired in September 2022. P.S. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

You *may* be able to get old versions using the google Apps Script REST API. If you go to https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.versions/list and use the "Try This Method" tab on the right (you will need your project ID) you may se a list of versions which you can use to retrieve the old code using the other URLs.

If all you see is a nextPageToken then there are no versions and you are out of luck.